# How to create buttons for input but not submit for rails with simple_form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

i got a simple_form for where i was getting inputs with radio buttons, but I decided that its not looking good and put my front-end shirt and decided to do something like this

http://tinypic.com/r/2rxy3hd/8

its basically a radio button but looks so much more nice, in this form.How can i achieve a button group like this ?I can give bootstrap classes to buttons but its basically only for submits, how can i take input from them?

this is my form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@campaign) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :message , :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 300px'} %>
    <!--<%= f.input :segment, as: :radio_buttons,
    collection: ['activeUser', 'allUser'], wrapper: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes %> -->

    <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :segment, [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class:"btn btn-success" %>

  </div>
<% end %>
```

my campaign model and its fields

```
  create_table :campaigns do |t|
      t.string :message
      t.string :campaignType
      t.string :segment
      t.string :receivers

      t.timestamps
```

Comment: Form for is used only when you have corresponding fields in your model .

Comment: @GhostBuster i know that thats why i gave it segment as field.

Comment: Can you post your model ?

Comment: @GhostBuster look at the edit pls